# Is there any ipmitool similar software for Windows?

Tags: free-software, open-source

We know many about Linux software [ipmitool](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ipmitool/), but I do not know if there is a similar ipmi management tool for Windows.

Anybody can recommend one for me?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Windows software. Furthermore this question is not answerable as is. Please read [guidelines on asking software recommendation questions](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information/352#352).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [ipmiutil](http://ipmiutil.sourceforge.net/).

- runs on Linux / Windows / Solaris / FreeBSD / MacOS
- source license is BSD 2.0

Answer (score 0):

There is also [IPMICFG](https://www.supermicro.com/solutions/SMS_IPMI.cfm) which can be run on Windows and DOS. I don't know why it's hard to find download link to this, but I found it [here](ftp://ftp.supermicro.com/utility/IPMICFG/). It is official supermicro FTP server.